# nodejs gremlin update if exist or else create

Tags: node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I am using nodejs gremlin against AWS neptune, the requirement is to update properties if vertice exist, or else, create a new vertice, i tried below

```
g.V().has('event','id','1').
  fold().
  coalesce(unfold(),
           addV('event').property('id','1'))
```

but I got 'unfold is not defined' error, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably just need to import `unfold()` properly. Some common imports for working with Gremlin can be found [here](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_common_imports_2) but in your case I think you just need to do:

```
const __ = gremlin.process.statics
```

and then refer to `unfold()` as `__.unfold()` - or just import `unfold()` as a function explicitly to use it as you were using it.